# Finding/indexing multiple pieces of statements found with regex

Tags: python, regex, cpplint

I'm looking for a way to parse the Junit XML output of cpplint.py and categorize the results. Right now the output is put into a text file and I want to make a much easier to read report out of it. cpplint.py reports each error by line number, error, error category, and finally severity. Each error looks like this:
`65: { should almost always be at the end of the previous line [whitespace/braces] [4]` The linter also parses a bunch different files and lists them as one long string, most seem to be separated by newlines but some are not. Each file is broken up by a header like this:
`<testcase name="proj/apps/prod/nnj/src/prod1.cpp"><failure>`

I am trying to find a way to break each one down by project and present the data better. I tried using regex to iterate by line, but many errors run into the next line and they get missed, also it doesn't catch my headers.

Is this something I can accomplish with one regular expression, or would I need multiple?

Could I use regex to append the file and add newlines at the end of each error?

Also it would be nice if I could incorporate the main header:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="177" name="cpplint" tests="177">`

So I can account for total repo errors, but its the same issue.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far? You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Then give a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil).